# Python Code for Particle Swarm Optimization

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, hyperparameters, particle-swarm

Following is the equation for PSO with passive congregation:
[image: equation for PSO with passive congregation]

In this equation:
Ri is a particle randomly selected from a swarm
c3 is the passive congregation coefficient
r3 is a uniform random sequence in the range (0,1)

I am attempting to model the equation with the following

```
  R = np.random.rand(n_particles)
  rand3 = np.random.uniform(0,1)
  v[j] = w*v[j] + c1*(p_best[j] - c[j]) * \
    rand1 + c2*(g_best - c[j])*rand2 + c3 * \
      (R[j] - c[j]) *rand3
```

Which seems to work, but I can't find any difference between Standard PSO and PSO with Passive Congregation---do I need to change my code?

Comment: can anyone help with this problem?